# Random Valid ASIN via Products API?

Tags: amazon-product-api

I'm working on an algorithm that requires grabbing random Amazon products.  Is there a way to grab a random ASIN using the products api?  Alternatively, is there a database or list of valid ASINs somewhere from which I can sample?

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't an API available, but what comes next to it is the **ListMatchingProducts** API operation:

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_ListMatchingProducts.html

You can search by keyword or whatever you want and you will get back the ASINs in a handy xml response.

The products API has some example libraries, found here:

https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/178-5155936-5152515?ie=UTF8&group=products&section=products&version=latest

Comment: This looks promising!  Do you know of anyone that has tried to end up with random products through intelligently randomizing the string that's searched?  Maybe this is a much rarer need than I thought, but I'd prefer not to have any implicit bias in whatever products are brought up.

Comment: What you are trying is very interesting, but I think a a big challenge will be exactly what you have written, to do an intelligent randomization in order to not to get implicit bias. I've been searching for UPC/EAN lists for some time to achieve the same. This might be interesting for you too. http://www.upcdatabase.com/random_item.asp but they don't allow non human access, maybe you can find something similar. Or you just use the API I mentioned in my answer and create random upcs, the api will respond to them with valid ASINs or a not existing message. @jbbj94

Comment: Also take a look on the getMatchingProductsForID section, as I remember this one has a slightly better maximum request ratio per hour

Comment: Alright, I cooked up a solution that involves, grabbing a random valid english word, searching it, and taking a random asin of the returned results.  Two probs: 1) verrry slow, especially because need to retry if random word returns nothing, and so need to sleep between calls to prevent slow-down server error.  2) I think this biases towards books and other media, due to the chance that a word will only have to do with a random book/movie title (e.g. searching "capricious" or something like that).  Guess that will have to do for testing for now.

Comment: That sound like a nice solution though! What products are you interested in in general? @jbbj94

Comment: i'm designing it to be able to make arbitrarily distal connections between products, regardless of category, hence the generality I'm gunning for here.  I'd like to limit products to a smaller subset for the time being, but I haven't found a list of words that field an unbiased subset of a category (e.g. shoes) to use so far.  May just make one by hand and use that for the time being (though, if you have any pointers on good keywords for product categories, I'd like to have them - Im brand new to this!